# How to create SVG with grid lines using D3JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, svg

I am planning to build a graph that will be designed by user by drag drop. I want to add grid lines to it. Currently I doing like:

```
var svg = d3.select("#canvas").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {

        svg.append("line")
            .attr("x1", i*60)
            .attr("y1", 0)
            .attr("x2", i*60)
            .attr("y2", 600)
            .attr("stroke-width", 0.5)
            .attr("stroke", "grey");
        svg.append("line")
            .attr("x1", 0)
            .attr("y1", i * 60)
            .attr("x2", 600)
            .attr("y2", i * 60)
            .attr("stroke-width", 0.5)
            .attr("stroke", "grey");

}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Also, except the first and last lines in the grid, the other lines are appearing thick.

https://jsfiddle.net/krishnasarma/rnyzkfrf/

Any help with simple drag drop of an image/object is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Only 1/2 of the first and last lines are visible as the rest is outside your viewport.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below code

index.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
    font: 12px Arial;
}

text.shadow {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2.5px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    stroke-opacity: 0.7;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid path {
          stroke-width: 0;
}

.area {
    fill: lightsteelblue;
      stroke-width: 0;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 35, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5);

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// function for the x grid lines
function make_x_axis() {
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(5)
}

// function for the y grid lines
function make_y_axis() {
  return d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(5)
}

// Get the data
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

    // Add the filled area
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("d", area);

    // Draw the x Grid lines
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(make_x_axis()
            .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
        )

    // Draw the y Grid lines
    svg.append("g")            
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .call(make_y_axis()
            .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
        )

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    // Add the text label for the X axis
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + 
                             (height+margin.bottom) + ")")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Date");

    // Add the white background to the y axis label for legibility
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("x", margin.top - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("class", "shadow")
        .text("Price ($)");

    // Add the text label for the Y axis
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("x", margin.top - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Price ($)");

    // Add the title
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", (width / 2))     
        .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("font-size", "16px")
        .style("text-decoration", "underline")
        .text("Price vs Date Graph");

});

</script>
</body>
```

data.csv

```
date,close
1-May-12,58.13
30-Apr-12,53.98
27-Apr-12,67.00
26-Apr-12,89.70
25-Apr-12,99.00
24-Apr-12,130.28
23-Apr-12,166.70
20-Apr-12,234.98
19-Apr-12,345.44
18-Apr-12,443.34
17-Apr-12,543.70
16-Apr-12,580.13
13-Apr-12,605.23
12-Apr-12,622.77
11-Apr-12,626.20
10-Apr-12,628.44
9-Apr-12,636.23
5-Apr-12,633.68
4-Apr-12,624.31
3-Apr-12,629.32
2-Apr-12,618.63
30-Mar-12,599.55
29-Mar-12,609.86
28-Mar-12,617.62
27-Mar-12,614.48
26-Mar-12,606.98
d3noob’s block #e1aa
```

Comment: I don't have any data upfront. I need to create a blank layout.